# Wifi not working asus x550ca

Tags: wireless

The wifi on my asus x550ca laptop is not working. Ethernet works fine in ubuntu but wifi does not work. Wifi works just fine when I boot up windows 8.1 though. Is there any special driver I have to install?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Here is the link to see the whole wireless-info.txt http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7844345/

Comment: Please have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593848/254422

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and paste this command:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

Reboot and wifi should work.

You may have to toggle your fn keys to remove the hard block after rebooting.

Here is the [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558) with full details by varun and chili555.

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes. Type *drivers* into the Dash and choose *Additional Drivers* application. It will show list of proprietary drivers that fits to your hardware. You can choose one for your WiFi card.

Comment: It says that there is no additional drivers available. What do I do now?